# Dialogflow / Ошибка после двух неправильных сообщений (ключевых слов)

Tags: dialogflow

Есть intent, когда пользователь пишет сообщения боту (определенное слово), идет дальше follow-up intent (дочерний). Когда ключевое слово если неправильное, ответ дается из default fallback intent.
Проблема в том, что когда дважды неправильно напишешь ключевое слово, считает все неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

Увеличить продолжительность жизни контекста, по умолчанию стояла 2